# combining two fit results

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, error-propagation, mean-square-error, weighted-least-squares

I have got two different kind of data points $(x_i, y_i)$. Because one kind are the result of several measurements of the same object I know their statistical error $\Delta x_i, \Delta y_i $ for $x_i$ and $y_i$. For the other one I do not now the statistical error. Thus, I am doing 2 separate fits ($y_i = a_i \cdot x^2  + b_i \cdot x + c_i $ with $ i=1, 2$) for the two kinds of data point using $\chi^2$ fits / Deming regression.

Result: $a_i, b_i, c_i, \Delta a_i, \Delta b_i, \Delta c_i$
Now I want to combine the two fit result to one functions including uncertainties:
$$ y_m = (a_m \pm \Delta a_m) \cdot x^2 + (b_m \pm \Delta b_m) \cdot x + (c_m \pm \Delta c_m) $$
using weighted mean by using the $\frac{1}{\Delta a_i}, \frac{1}{\Delta b_i}, \frac{1}{\Delta c_i} $ as weights.
Can I just use:
$$ y_m = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \cdot \frac{1}{(\Delta y_i)^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(\Delta y_i)^2}} $$
where $\Delta y_i $ is got by Gaussian error propagation: $\Delta y_i = \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial p_{j,i}} \cdot \Delta p_{j,i} $ with $ p_{1,i} = a_i, p_{2,i} = b_i,  p_{3,i} = c_i$.
And
$$ \sigma_{y_m}^2 =  \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\Delta y_i²} } $$

As $ y_m $ will be a broken rational function (of order 2) and not a polynomial of order 2 anymore and there are no separate errors for the fitted parameters anymore, I hope there is a better way.

P.S.: Concerning SW: I am using (in Python) is numpy/scipy and ROOT.

Comment: I don't see the reasoning for doing "two separate fits", both of quadratic polynomials if I understand your problem.  Repeated measurements at the same argument are in a sense naturally weighted by a least squares fit.  If anything I'd be concerned about the sensitivity of the least squares fit to outliers.

Comment: You are right - both are of quadratic polynomials. But there are no repeated measurements in both datasets. Doing just one fit and just put the individual points instead of the mean and error of the one data set I would loose information.  My data points: $x_{1,1} / y_{1,1},  x_{1,2} / y_{1,2}, ...$ and $x_{2,1} \pm \Delta x_{2,1} / y_{2,1} \pm \Delta y_{2,1}, ... $